# Javascript replace regex to accept only numbers, including negative ones, two decimals, replace 0s in the beginning, except if number is 0

Tags: javascript, regex

The question became a bit long, but it explains the expected behaviour.

```
let regex = undefined;

const format = (string) => string.replace(regex, '');

format('0')
//0
format('00')
//0
format('02')
//2
format('-03')
//-3
format('023.2323')
//23.23
format('00023.2.3.2.3')
//23.23
```

In the above example you can see the expected results in comments.

To summarize. I'm looking for a regex not for test, for replace which formats a string:

- removes `0`s from the beginning if it's followed by any numbers
- allows decimal digits, but just 2
- allows negative numbers
- allows decimal points, but just one (followed by min 1, max 2 decimal digits)

The last one is a bit difficult to handle as the user can't enter period at the same time, I'll have two formatter functions, one will be the input in the input field, and one for the closest valid value at the moment (for example `'2.'` will show `'2.'` in the input field, but the handler will receive the value `'2'`).

If not big favour, I'd like to see explanation of the solution, why it works, and what's the purpose of which part.

Right now I'm having `string.replace(/[^\d]+(\.\[^\d{1,2}])+|^0+(?!$)/g, '')`, but it doesn't fulfill all the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this code:

```js
const arr = ['0', '00', '02', '-03', '023.2323', '00023.2.3.2.3', '-23.2.3.2.3']

var narr = []

// to remove leading zeroes
const re1 = /^([+-]?)0+?(?=\d)/
// to remove multiple decimals
const re2 = /^([+-]?\d*\.\d+)\.(\d+).*/

arr.forEach( el => {
   el = el.replace(re1, '$1').replace(re2, '$1$2')
   if (el.indexOf('.') >= 0)
      el = Number(el).toFixed(2)
   narr.push(el)
})

console.log(narr)
//=> ["0", "0", "2", "-3", "23.23", "23.23"]
```

Comment: Great solution, however, when combining negative with multiple decimals for example  `-23.2.3.2.3` returns `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't bound to the `String#replace` method, you can try this regex:

```
/^([+-])?0*(?=\d+$|\d+\.)(\d+)(?:\.(\d{1,2}))?$/
```

<sup>[Inspect on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OAJ1be/1)</sup>

It collects the parts of the number into capturing groups, as follows:

1. Sign: the sign of the number, `+`, `-` or `undefined`
2. Integer: the integer part of the number, without leading zeros
3. Decimal: the decimal part of the number, `undefined` if absent

This regex won't match if more then 2 decimal places present. To strip it instead, use this:

```
/^([+-])?0*(?=\d+$|\d+\.)(\d+)(?:\.(\d{1,2})\d*)?$/
```

<sup>[Inspect on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kQgnBt/1)</sup>

To format a number using one of the above, you can use something like:

```js
let regex = /^([+-])?0*(?=\d+$|\d+\.)(\d+)(?:\.(\d{1,2}))?$/
const format = string => {
  try{
    const [, sign, integer, decimal = ''] = string.match(regex)
    return `${(sign !== '-' ? '' : '-')}${integer}${(decimal && `.${decimal}`)}`
  }catch(e){
    //Invalid format, do something
    return
  }
}

console.log(format('0'))
//0
console.log(format('00'))
//0
console.log(format('02'))
//2
console.log(format('-03'))
//-3
console.log(format('023.23'))
//23.23
console.log(format('023.2323'))
//undefined (invalid format)
console.log(format('00023.2.3.2.3'))
//undefined (invalid format)


//Using the 2nd regex
regex = /^([+-])?0*(?=\d+$|\d+\.)(\d+)(?:\.(\d{1,2})\d*)?$/


console.log(format('0'))
//0
console.log(format('00'))
//0
console.log(format('02'))
//2
console.log(format('-03'))
//-3
console.log(format('023.23'))
//23.23
console.log(format('023.2323'))
//23.23
console.log(format('00023.2.3.2.3'))
//undefined (invalid format)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use pattern with 3 capturing groups. In the replacement, use all 3 groups `"$1$2$3"`

If the string after the replacement is empty, return a single zero.

If the string is not empty, concat group 1, group 2 and group 3 where for group 3, remove all the dots except for the first one to keep it for the decimal and take the first 3 characters (which is the dot and 2 digits)

```
^([-+]?)0*([1-9]\d*)((?:\.\d+)*)|0+$
```

*In parts*

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[-+]?` Match an optional `+` or `-`
- `)` Close group
- `0*` Match 0+ times a zero
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[1-9]\d*` Match a digit 1-9 followed by optional digits 0-9
- `)` Close group
- `(` Capture **group 3**

  - `(?:\.\d+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching a dot and a digit
- `)` Close group
- `|` Or
- `0+` Match 1+ times a zero
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IhPoSs/1)

```js
const strings = ['0', '00', '02', '-03', '023.2323', '00023.2.3.2.3', '-23.2.3.2.3', '00001234', '+0000100005.0001']
let pattern = /^([-+]?)0*([1-9]\d*)((?:\.\d+)*)|0+$/;

let format = s => {
  s = s.replace(pattern, "$1$2$3");
  return s === "" ? '0' : s.replace(pattern, (_, g1, g2, g3) =>
    g1 + g2 + g3.replace(/(?!^)\./g, '').substring(0, 3)
  );
};

strings.forEach(s => console.log(format(s)));
```